# Calculate number of

Tags: datetime, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, date-difference

Given a start date such as 1/1/2014, I would like to determine the number of awards due.
The schedule for awards: 
First award - four years of membership.
All other awards: awarded every three years, after the first award.
J4 is the cell with the start date. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
=IF(J4="","", 
 IF(Today()-J4<4,"",
 IF(Today()-J4=4,"1",
 ((((Today()-J4)/356)-4)/3)+1)))
```

However, I feel like something is missing. I am just not sure how to confirm this properly calculates all scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(IF(DATEDIF(J4, TODAY(), "Y")<4, , 1+
 QUOTIENT(DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(J4)+4, MONTH(J4), DAY(J4)), TODAY(), "Y"), 3)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED Please try:

```
=if((DATEDIF(J4,TODAY(),"y"))<4,0,1+INT(DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(J4)+4,MONTH(J4),DAY(J4)),TODAY(),"y")/3))
```